# Do browsers with JavaScript disabled, disable inline JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know if web browsers with Javascript disabled still allow inline Javascript like the following or if they disable that too.

```
<p onClick="alert('You just clicked a paragraph element.');">Click Here</p>
```

Comment: can't test on your own browser?

Comment: If JavaScript is disabled, it's disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If JavaScript is disabled it is disabled everywhere - so the onClick event will not work.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, all JavaScript is disabled.

Answer (score 2):

All JavaScript will be disabled, including inline script.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable javascript after listeners have been established, the functionality may remain

Answer (score 0):

simple answer: **YES THEY DO**